# Having trouble deploying rails application [bundler: failed to load command: rake ] cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to deploy a rails 6 application using rails buildpack on ibmcloud cloudfoundry but in vain. I get a rake error bundler: failed to load command: rake
https://i.stack.imgur.com/owDQO.png

Answer (score 0):

So after digging around and getting to understand my logs better, I had to update bundle globally for some reason and in due process updated rake. Then I had to create a rake task and put it in the lib folder under task. This automatically gets called in the Rakefile.
After that, in my manifest file, i had inlcuded the command: bundle exec rake cf:on_first_instance db:migrate && bundle exec rails s -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV, which now was able to be called while deploying the rails 6 app on cf and run the rake tasks there after.